# Solr Highlighting return id

Tags: java, php, apache, solr, lucene

Hi Iam making a simple highlight query

```
select?fl=name&hl.fl=name&hl=on&indent=on&q=cubo&wt=json
```

The problem is the result. I Dont want the id in the json response

```
"highlighting":{
    "fbd29a94-b53d-4de0-8e74-046bf1f921cd":{
      "name":["<em>Cubo</em> de Roda Dianteiro para Ford"]},
    "f6ddf7a0-352e-4789-8e29-ca927274c5cc":{
      "name":["<em>Cubo</em> de Roda Traseiro para Jac Motors"]},
    "1901086a-1867-4c8a-a2b7-ce7578e352c3":{
      "name":["<em>Cubo</em> de Roda Dianteiro para Nissan"]}}
```

I Want this... is Possible ? How i do that ?

```
"highlighting":[
    {"name":["<em>Cubo</em> de Roda Dianteiro para Ford"]},
    {"name":["<em>Cubo</em> de Roda Traseiro para Jac Motors"]},   
    {"name":["<em>Cubo</em> de Roda Dianteiro para Nissan"]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's not possible, since there might be documents in the result set that no highlighting is performed for (i.e. it doesn't match terms that are highlightable, but it still matches the document).

If you *really* need this, you can do it in your middleware (since you've tagged PHP, I'll use that for pseudo code):

```
// keep highlighted entries in sequence
$highlights = [];

foreach ($hits as $doc) {
    // if we have a highlighting element for this document
    if (!empty($result['highlighting'][$doc['id']])) {
        // keep the highlighted text
        $highlights[] = $result['highlighting'][$doc['id']];
    } else {
        // .. and if we don't, add a null element so indices match
        $highlights[] = null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Iam sad but Thank you!